# SQLAlchemy circular dependency - how to solve it?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, circular-dependency

I have two tables, `News` and `Files`:

```
# unrelated columns removed
class News(db.Model): 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    file_id_logo = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('files.id'))
    logo = db.relationship('File', lazy=False)

class File(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    news_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('news.id'))
    news = db.relationship('News', lazy=False, backref=db.backref('files'))
```

After adding the `file_id_logo` fkey, SQLalchemy raised a CircularDependencyError.
I've already tried `post_update=True` in the `logo` relation, but it did not change anything.

What's the proper way to solve this?

The following cases are possible (in case it matters):

- A File has no or exactly one News assigned.
- If a File has no News, there's also no News with this file referenced as its logo.
- There can be multiple Files for a single News, but only one of these Files can be its `logo`.
- So if a News has a `logo`, the referenced File also has this news as its `news`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

use_alter – passed to the underlying ForeignKeyConstraint to indicate the constraint should be generated/dropped externally from the CREATE TABLE/ DROP TABLE statement. See that classes’ constructor for details.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKeyConstraint.params.use_alter

Comment: Worked fine to get rid of the error, but it broke some other relationships. So I decided to simply get rid of the ForeignKey. Accepting it anyway since the answer itself is correct.

Comment: @ThiefMaster You probably just needed to set primaryjoin on your relation - they cannot determine join direction when there's multiple relations/backrefs between two tables.

Comment: I found the information here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/constraints.html